# Get nested values from JSON with angularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I need to get nested products from JSON to my html in `<div ng-repeat="order in orders"></div>` I tried many versions of getting products values(name, description etc.) but none of them works. How to do this ?

JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":3,
      "date":"00:00:00",
      "user":{  
         "id":1,
      },
      "orderState":{  
         "id":1,
      },
      "products":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Bosch POF 1200",
            "description":"1200W",
            "enabled":true,
            "price":459,
         },
         {  
            "id":9,
            "name":"Graphite 58G782",
            "description":"a",
            "enabled":true,
            "price":429,
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Controller

```
OrdersService.retrieveAllByCurrentUser().then(function(response) {
  $scope.orders = response.data;
  console.log(response.data);
}, function(error) {
  registerError(error, 'retrieving all orders');
});
```

Comment: What was your best attempt? What did you expect it to do and what did it do instead? Post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a nested `ng-repeat` like this to access the `products` information:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
  <div ng-repeat="product in order.products">
    <h1 ng-bind="product.name"></h1>
    <p ng-bind="product.description"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For each `order` it will go into `order.products` and loop out the information as `product`, then you can access the information in `product` via dot notation, like `product.name` for example.

Answer (score 3):

The ng-repeat directive creates a new scope, which means that you should be able to loop through the products within it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
<div ng-repeat="product in order.products"> e.g. {{product.name}} </div>
</div>
```

I would also advise to write a directive for dealing with that kind of stuff, because your code can get unreadable really fast. Don't take my word for it though as I am no Angular expert.

Comment: There's no need for a directive unless it's going to be used on multiple places in the code.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz you're absolutely right. I just felt like pointing it out, because if you ask such an easy question you might also be interested in learning some good practices for bigger projects :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do nested `ng-repeat` in html

```
 <div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <div ng-repeat "product in order.products">
        <span>{product.name}}</span>
        <span>{{product.description}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```